# IOS/Objective-C: Detect Button Press in Custom Tableview Cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

For a feed View controller, I have a tableview with some custom cells that have buttons for like, comment and share  I would like to perform different actions depending on which button is pushed.

My initial thought was to simply wire the buttons in the custom cell in storyboard to action methods in the custom cell.  However, I have gotten confused on how methods in the custom cell .m file interact with the TableView in the View Controller.

```
- (IBAction)likeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
 CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
//do something
}
```

Can anyone clarify whether a button push in a cell can be wired in storyboard and how this plays with the delegate methods on the viewcontroller, cellforrowatindexpath and didselectrowatindexpath?

Or if this is not the right way to do it, would appreciate any suggestions on better way.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using the `delegate` or `tags`, you can simply use **`blocks`** to do that. `Blocks` are much more easy and simple to use than the `delegate` pattern and recommended.

In `Swift` too, you shall see the extensive use of `closures (blocks in Objective-C)` than any other pattern.

**Example:**

**1. `UITableViewDataSource` Methods**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.likeButtonTapHandler = ^{
        NSLog(@"Like Button Tapped");
        //ADD YOUR CODE HERE
    };
    cell.commentButtonTapHandler = ^{
        NSLog(@"Comment Button Tapped");
        //ADD YOUR CODE HERE
    };
    cell.shareButtonTapHandler = ^{
        NSLog(@"Share Button Tapped");
        //ADD YOUR CODE HERE
    };
    return cell;
}
```

**2. Custom UITableView Cell**

```
@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^likeButtonTapHandler)(void);
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^commentButtonTapHandler)(void);
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^shareButtonTapHandler)(void);

@end

@implementation TableViewCell

- (IBAction)likeButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    self.likeButtonTapHandler();

}

- (IBAction)commentButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    self.commentButtonTapHandler();
}

- (IBAction)shareButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    self.shareButtonTapHandler();
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this method. Roohul method might work too but this was very easy to implement

Comment: Sure..happy coding 

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways. Preferably the first one keeping in mind Objective-C design pattern .

- Using delegate pattern

  You can send a call back to your view controller passing the Button id(can be a tag or enum) and the cell object and handling the stuff there.
- Using tag according to the `indexPath`

  For example if you have just rows and no columns, then you can assign the buttons tags as per their row number and button type and if you have rows and section, you can assign tag as per row and section number and then assign selector to the buttons in `CellForRowAtIndexPath` then you can get the row number from decoding the tag of `sender`

Now, expanding on the first approach, no need to get the position of the buttons. Just call the delegate method for that button which will be observed in your ViewControler.

In your Custom cell Class.

```
@protocol YourCellButtonsDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)likeButtonTappedForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell;
- (void)commentButtonTappedForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell;
- (void)shareButtonTappedForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell;
@end

@interface YourCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <YourCellButtonsDelegate> buttonsDelegate;
@end
```

Example of Action method for Like button would be like.

```
- (IBAction)likeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.buttonsDelegate likeButtonTappedForCell:self];
}
```

And in your `ViewController` class in `CellForRowAtIndex` method after initializing and assigning to YourCell, assign the delegate as follows

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"YourCellIdentifier";

    YourCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //do your stuffs here.
    cell.delegate = self
}
```

And implement the delegate method as follows.

```
- (void)likeButtonTappedForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
   //you can get the row from the indexPath here.

}
```

And don't forget to confirm the delegate in your ViewController class.

Comment: Sorry, I am dense about this.  Could you suggest code for first approach?